# How to teleport nearby villagers to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to move all my villagers back to the middle of my town. I'm trying to work with the /tp command, but almost every time it says Entity not found.

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager,dx=300,dy=300,dz=300] @p

/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager,distance=200] @p
```

The only time it worked was when I did this:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:sheep] @p
```

and it teleported like a hundred sheep into me.

Is there a reason the above ones wouldn't work?

1.14.4, using LAN mode with one other person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first command doesn't always work because it's selecting a box that extends 300 blocks in the x, y, and z directions from your current location.  If there's no villager in that box, they're not going to be teleported.  You shouldn't be using the `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` selector arguments without the `z`, `y`, and `z` selectors in most cases anyway.  This kind of selection is best reserved for finding a target within a very specific box, which is probably not the case here.

The second command doesn't work (except in very specific contrived circumstances) because you are trying to find a villager *exactly* 200 blocks away.  For various reasons, this is basically impossible in normal gameplay.  Fortunately it's relatively easy to fix this by searching for a villager less than or equal to 200 blocks away:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager,distance=..200] @p
```

If you only want to teleport a single villager instead of multiple villagers, it's simple to impose that limit as well:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager,distance=..200,limit=1,sort=nearest] @p
```

or to get a random villager:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:villager,distance=..200,limit=1,sort=random] @p
```